# I want Create Url like in www.mysite.com/home/details/1/lesson1 in mvc with Url.action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want create url in mvc with `Url.Action`

my code is

```
Url.Action( "Details", "Home",  new   { id= item.Id  ,title=item.Title},  "http" )
```

but this code create link  like in

```
http://localhost:45201/Admin/Home/Details/1?title=lesson1
```

I want like in

```
http://localhost:45201/Admin/Home/Details/1/lesson1
```

Comment: How are you defining your routes?

Comment: depends on how you define your routes. are you using convention-based or attribute routing?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you define your routes.

use this for convention-based routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AdminHomeDetails",
    url: "Admin/Home/Details/{id}/{title}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Details" }
);
```

**OR** use this for attribute routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("Admin/Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller {
    //GET Admin/Home/Details/1/lesson1
    [Route("Details/{id:int}/{title}")]
    public ActionResult Details(int id, string title) { ... }
}
```

for attribute routing don't forget to map attribute routes before convention-based routes

```
public class RouteConfig {

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //...and then convention-based routes.

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
}
```

Check [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) for more on attribute routing.

Comment: thanks , this code [Route("Details/{id}/{title})"]   Where used?

Comment: That is attribute routing. read about it here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: I use this attribute routing in routConfig But again not